# On creation of Inventory Transfer I get error: You cannot create an inventory detail for this item

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I need to create an inventory transfer with suite script 2.1, when I do
`rec.getCurrentSublistSubrecord('inventory', 'inventorydetail')`
I get an error message "You cannot create an inventory detail for this item"

I get the same error on non-dynamic record too (getSublistValue)

The item is a serial item, I can configure inventory detail via the UI in Netsuite but not in the suitescript. Any idea why?